# TypeScript 2: Calling method of class, not object

Tags: angularjs, class, typescript, ionic-framework

I have found a great [service](https://github.com/ErikSchierboom/ionic2-audio-recorder/blob/master/app/services/audiorecorder.ts) for recording audio in `Ionic`.
But there is at least one thing that I do not understand:

For example, in line 25:

```
this.MediaPlugin.startRecord();
```

**Question**: Why does it call on `this.MediaPlugin.startRecord()` and not `this.mediaPlugin.startRecord()` where `this.mediaPlugin` is an object and `MediaPlugin` a class?

If the class uses `this.MediaPlugin` to do the actions why does it return in the `get` method an object?

complete code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MediaPlugin } from 'ionic-native';

export enum AudioRecorderState {
    Ready,
    Recording,
    Recorded,
    Playing
}

@Injectable()
export class AudioRecorder {
  mediaPlugin: MediaPlugin = null;
  state: AudioRecorderState = AudioRecorderState.Ready;

  get MediaPlugin(): MediaPlugin {
    if (this.mediaPlugin == null) {
      this.mediaPlugin = new MediaPlugin('../Library/NoCloud/recording.wav');
    }

    return this.mediaPlugin;
  }

  startRecording() {
    this.MediaPlugin.startRecord();
    this.state = AudioRecorderState.Recording;
  }

  stopRecording() {
    this.MediaPlugin.stopRecord();
    this.state = AudioRecorderState.Recorded;
  }

  startPlayback() {
    this.MediaPlugin.play();
    this.state = AudioRecorderState.Playing;
  }

  stopPlayback() {
    this.MediaPlugin.stop();
    this.state = AudioRecorderState.Ready;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`this.MediaPlugin` is the reference to the `get`. Using this syntax, it'll construct the `MediaPlugin` on the first call, but use the constructed on following calls.

(This solutions seems a little weird to me too, since it'd make more sense to just use the constructor in the `AudioRecorder` class to init `this.mediaPlugin`, and then use `this.mediaPlugin` elsewhere)

Answer (score 0):

First of all following method is a getter and I guess it's an attempt to implement readonly property with lazy initialization.

```
get MediaPlugin(): MediaPlugin {
    if (this.mediaPlugin == null) {
        this.mediaPlugin = new MediaPlugin('../Library/NoCloud/recording.wav');
    }

    return this.mediaPlugin;
}
```

So when you try to access this.MediaPlugin for the first time, new instance of MediaPlugin is being created. And when you instantiate AudioRecorder and do not use it (for some reasons) it helps you to save memory not creating instance of MediaPlugin immediately. (see [Lazy loading pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading))

**Answering you question:**

> Why does it call on this.MediaPlugin.startRecord() and not
>   this.mediaPlugin.startRecord() where this.mediaPlugin is an object and
>   MediaPlugin a class?

Typescript does not provide any common mechanism of lazy loading and the way to implement it is to create private property with a getter method (as in your AudioRecorder class).

Calling `this.MediaPlugin.startRecord()` you kind of encapsulating creation and manipulation logic of MediaPlugin instance.

Answer (score 0):

## Naming conventions

Someone messed up with regards to naming conventions. The name of the property should be `mediaPlugin`, not `MediaPlugin`.

The reason that the property accessor is called `MediaPlugin` is that there is already a backing field called `mediaPlugin`.

Some would argue that the backing field should be called `_mediaPlugin`. Others would argue that this would go against naming conventions. If the latter is the case, you could call it `mediaPluginField`.

```
class AudioRecorder {
  mediaPluginField: MediaPlugin = null;

  get mediaPlugin(): MediaPlugin {
    if (this.mediaPluginField === null) {
      this.mediaPluginField = new MediaPlugin('../Library/NoCloud/recording.wav');
    }

    return this.mediaPluginField;
  }
}
```

## Dependency inversion

However, as @Vladyslav Yefremov points out, an arguably better option would be to inject the `MediaPlugin` dependency through the constructor or pull it from some kind of service locator.

```
class AudioRecorder {
  constructor(private mediaPlugin: MediaPlugin) { }
}
```

or

```
class AudioRecorder {
    private mediaPlugin: MediaPlugin;

    constructor(mediaPlugin: MediaPlugin) {
        this.mediaPlugin = mediaPlugin;
    }
}
```

## Lazy instantiation

I do not immediately see the need to instantiate the media plugin lazily, as the audio recorder needs a media plugin for all actions.

However, it could be because the media plugin has the side effect of loading the media file when instantiated. If this is the case, the media plugin property is instantiated lazily to delay the opening of the resource until it is actually needed, i.e. when the AudioRecorder is needed.